# understand complex expression in C

Tags: c, increment, dereference

Help me please understand the following expression:

(seen in a book)

```
*((int *)marks + i++) = i+1
```

A large number of increments and symbols dereference confusing!

Comment: I hope the book had this as a bad example.

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: If the book's author didn't write it as a bad example, then probably he has no friends.

Comment: Looks like undefined behaviour to me.

Comment: It is indeed @KerrekSB. I've put as an answer if any thing to guard against more SO questions emanating from this literary travesty.

Comment: What book is this? I hope it's not bull-Schildt!

Comment: Assuming you first remove cases of UB like `i++ = i` then the way to understand a complicated expression is to break it into a sequence of simpler expressions that should produce the same result. e.g. `*((int *)marks + offset) = newval` is the same as `int *intp = marks; int *valp = intp + offset; *valp = newval;`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
(int *)marks
```

cast marks to a int pointer

```
+ i++
```

add i at marks (chaging the address pointed) and then increments i by 1

```
*(...) = i+1
```

set the VALUE of the cell pointed by our pointer to i+1 (pay attention at the fact that i as already been incremented before, so it will be greater of 2 by the start of the instruction.

I hope this is an example f how you should NOT write the code :)

Answer (score 5):

I hope the book had this as a bad example, because the behavior of that is undefined.

`(int *)marks` interprets `marks` (whatever that may be) as a pointer to `int`, then we have the result of `i++` added to that. This pointer is dereferenced and `i+1` is assigned to the corresponding object.

This expression has no defined behavior because it reads and modifies `i` at two different subexpressions that are not sequenced one before the other.

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there any guarantee about the evaluation order of left and right member? I remember the answer being no, but I could not track the exact part of the specs in which this is mentioned.

Comment: No, as I indicated there is no sequence point, so the left and right expressions could be evaluated in any order, intertwined, in parallel whatever.

Answer (score 5):

**Burn the book.**

The behaviour of the statement is **undefined** due to there being no sequence points. A far simpler case to understand is `i++ = i` which is also undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Note: As others have said, the `i++` expression is undefined behavior. In g++, the `i++` operation will be executed as follows:

```
// Pointer to some data.
void* marks = ???;
// Typecast to an integer pointer
int* marksIntPointer = (int*)marks;
// Move the position in memory. I am assuming that 'marks' is an array.
int* marksIntPointerOffset = marksIntPointer + i;
// Undefined behaviour, could take place here or before, depending on the compiler (as others have said).
i++;
// Set the value of the desired memory.
*marksIntPointerOffset = i+1;
```

Comment: If it wasn't for an undefined behaviour... I mean, `i++` will be executed after `int* marksIntPointerOffset = marksIntPointer + i;`, correct. But will `i + 1` be evaluated before or after `i++`?

Comment: -1, this answer is misleading, since it presents this as a linear flow. In fact the evaluation of `i+i` in the last row can appear at any point inbetween. In that, reading of `i` may even return an invalid value, if the `i++` operation can't be done in one instruction.

Comment: Unless g++ compiles incorrectly, it is defined behavior. Check my edit.

Comment: Testing with the compiler is not enough. Compiler is allowed to misbehave in undefined behaviour.

Comment: @elimirks, first for your update, this is C and not C++ :) Then testing with a compiler tells you nothing about undefined behavior. The essence of undefined behavior is that no compiler has to detect it or do anything about it. Only for "constraint violations" a compiler must give a diagnostic.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I read up on undefined behavior regarding the incrementation operators and now understand. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned expression yields an ***undefined behavior***.

*C99 6.5 §2* states:

> *1) Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value
>   modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.*
>
> 2) *Furthermore, **the prior value shall be read only to determine the value to be stored**.*

---

1) Storing and modifying the value of variable within a single expression is pretty straightforward:

```
i = ++i;
i++ = i;
++i = 7;
```

as well as modifying the value of the same variable multiple times within a single expression:

```
j = ++i + ++i;
```

2) ***Reading only to determine the value to be stored*** might be a bit tricky though. This means that even the following (just like the previous examples) invoke the *undefined behavior*:

```
j = (i + 1) + i++;
a[i++] = i;  
*(ptr + i++) = i;
```

as well as:

```
*((int *)marks + i++) = i+1
```

You might look at: [Undefined behavior and sequence points](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4176328/1168156) as well :)

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, the behavior is undefined; by getting rid of the `++` operator, the following code would be well-defined (but still ugly as sin):

```
*((int *)marks + i) = i+1
```

Here's how it breaks down:

```
         marks               -- take the expression marks
  (int *)marks               -- cast it as a pointer to int
  (int *)marks + i           -- offset i integer elements from that address
*((int *)marks + i)          -- deference the result to get an array element
*((int *)marks + i) = i+1    -- assign the result of i+1 to that element
```

This is essentially treating `marks` as an array of `int`, and assigning the result of `i+1` to the `i`'th element:

```
int *mp = (int *) marks;
mp[i] = i+1
```

The original expression was trying to do

```
mp[i++] = i+1
```

which invokes undefined behavior.  Since the order in which `i++` and `i+1` are evaluated is not specified; the compiler is free to evaluate them in any order it feels like.  Since `i++` has a side effect (updating the value of `i`), this means that you will get different results based on the platform, optimization settings, even the surrounding code.  The language standard explicitly leaves the behavior *undefined* so that the compiler isn't required to handle this code in any particular way.  You will get *a* result, but it's not guaranteed to be consistent from compiler to compiler (or even from run to run).

Answer (score -2):

Let's see.

*((int *)marks + i++) = i+1

-marks is cast to a pointer to int
-i is incremented by one
-the pointer (int *)marks is advanced by the value (i+1) using pointer arithmetic
-this pointer is now dereferenced, so...
-... the memory location to which it points is now written with the value of i+1